# How to render a collection of images in a view within a modal box

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a collection of images that our users upload in our `ASP.NET MVC` application.

Once users upload images, I save the images in the content/images folder of the web UI project  and populate files names into an List and then then render this object in an editor template within a `partial view`.

I am not sure why the images are  not rendering but following is my code:

**View**

```
<div class="bodyContent">
    @if (Model.RunEntryImagesDisplay != null && Model.RunEntryImagesDisplay.Count() > 0)
    {
        <span class="leftContent">
            @Html.Label("Images")
        </span><span class="rightContent"><span id="ImagesChildDialogLink" class="treeViewLink">
            Click here to View Images </span>
            <br />
            <span id="ImagesDisplayy"></span></span>
    }
</div>
<div id="Imagestreeview" title="Dialog Title" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal;
    overflow: scroll; width: 800px; height: 450px; display: none;">
    @if (Model.RunEntryImagesDisplay != null && Model.RunEntryImagesDisplay.Count() > 0)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.RunEntryImagesDisplay)
    }
</div>
```

**Editor Template**

```
@model RunLog.Domain.Entities.RunLogEntryImagesDisplay
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.FileStoredName, new { style = "width: 200px; height: 100px;" })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.FileStoredName)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.FileName, new { style = "width: 200px; height: 100px;" })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.FileName)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Checked)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Checked)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.FileExtension, new { style = "width: 200px; height: 100px;" })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.FileExtension)
<img src="@Url.Action("Image", Model.FileStoredName)" alt="Image" />
```

**JS Modal Box**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#ImagesChildDialogLink').click(function () {

        initImagesDailog();
    });


    function initImagesDailog() {
        var PartDialog;
        PartDialog = $("#Imagestreeview").dialog({ autoOpen: true, modal: false, resizable: true, draggable: true,
            stack: false, title: 'Parsed Test Exceptions', width: 1000, height: 400, buttons: { Close: function () {
                var btnText = '';
                $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane :button').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).text() == 'Close') {
                        btnText = 'Close';
                        $(this).text('Close');
                    }
                });
                if (btnText == 'Close') {
                    PartDialog.dialog("close");
                }
            }
            }
        });

        PartDialog.closest("div.ui-dialog").appendTo("#form");
    }

});
```

**Controller Action to render image**

public ActionResult Image(string file)
    {

```
    //byte[] image = 
    string loadLististFileName = file;
    string fileNamePath = loadLististFileName;
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileNamePath);
    string dirName = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileNamePath);

    var fileData = IOHelper.GetFileImageData(fileName, dirName);

    return File(fileData, "image/jpg");
}



public static byte[] GetFileImageData(this string fileName, string filePath)
{
    var fullFilePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}", filePath, fileName);
    if (!File.Exists(fullFilePath))
        throw new FileNotFoundException("The file does not exist.", fullFilePath);
    return File.ReadAllBytes(fullFilePath);
}
```

**EDIT**

I got it work, my editor template name was not the same as of the model List property. I didn't even need to use an action image to display. just used the image source tag.

Comment: As you found out the solution, [you can answer your question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and accept the answer so that everyone will see there's no more help needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, my editor template, the name of the cshtml was not the same as of the model List property. I didn't even need to use an action image to display. just used the image source tag and it works like a charm. Now I am going to use an image gallery plugin to make it all pretty with thumbnails and all that good stuff.  MVC is so touch wood.